# How to stop Prometheus alerts for terminated instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus to monitor a bunch of AWS EC2 instances.  The instances are automatically included through the `ec2_sd_config` configuration.  So scrape targets are automatically added because Prometheus periodically queries AWS to get a list of current instances.

I'm seeing a problem where I will get Prometheus alerts about an instance being down, but in reality what has happened is that the instance has been terminated.  I don't want to get alerts when the instance has been legitimately terminated or stopped.

Scraping is configured to happen like this:

```
scrape_interval:     30s
evaluation_interval: 30s
```

I don't have any specific refresh_interval configured for the ec2_sd_config, so I presume it is using [the default](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#ec2_sd_config):

> [ refresh_interval:  | default = 60s ]

Here's the ec2_sd_config--which has a filter to only include those instances that have a "running" state:
  ec2_sd_configs:

```
  - endpoint: ""
    region: us-east-1
    profile: MY_PROFILE
    refresh_interval: 1m
    port: 9100
    filters:
    - name: instance-state-name
      values:
      - running
    - name: vpc-id
      values:
      - vpc-abcdefg123
```

**Why do I get alerts for instances that were previously running, but are currently terminated?**

I suspect this *may* be happening due to a timing configuration or due to the filter.  Since I am scraping and evaluating rules every 30 seconds, but only updating the list of servers every minute, is that making it so Prometheus evaluates rules against instances that are no longer "running?"  Even if I updated the list of servers more frequently--say every 20 seconds--wouldn't there still be a chance that the rules would be evaluated against an instance that just got terminated?  Is this a race condition?  Or perhaps I should not filter the ec2_sd_config to just running instances?  The alerts seem to be "resolved" in a few minutes without intervention, but I want to eliminate the needless alerts.   Maybe my assumptions are just incorrect here--I'm hoping someone with Prometheus experience can help clear things up for me.

Comment: It could be timing, but we can't tell without poking at your prometheus instance. In general, you want alert thresholds long enough to handle those scenarios (alert if instance X is down for Y minutes). If you want to keep the delay as short as possible, reduce the scrape/evalutation/refresh intervals.

Comment: This is the alert that is firing:  - alert: Host_Down
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m